# how to use the simple-oauth2 library to make request application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

i have some code which perfectly work through mac terminal and giving me token from website

```
curl -XPOST "https://link.com/oauth/access_token" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "Accept: 1.0" \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials" \
--data-urlencode "client_id=myawesomeapp" \
--data-urlencode "client_secret=abc123" \
--data-urlencode "scope=read write"
```

I want to do request through nodejs without curl request. website giving link on npm library simple-oauth2, but my code does not work.

my not working version of this

```
const credentials = {
  client: {
    id: 'myawesomeapp',
    secret: 'abc123'
  },
  auth: {
    tokenHost: 'https://link.com',
    tokenPath: '/oauth/access_token'
  },
  http: {
    'headers.authorization': 'headers.Accept = application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
};


 oauth2 = oauth2.create(credentials);

 oauth2.accessToken.create()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an x-www-form-urlencoded content type, you'll probably need to also update the authorisation method in your options to *form* (its default is *header*). I.e.

```
const credentials = {
    /*
       your existing config
    */
    options: {
        authorizationMethod: 'body'
    }
}
```

Hopefully that should do the trick...